# Trying to get data from web-service in java

Tags: java, json, swing, web-services, httpurlconnection

```
[
    {
        "title": "ginger",
        "id": "38",
        "product_id": "17",
        "product_logo": "imagePath/Desert_0.jpg?itok=Uvm6nxpY",
        "product_logo_1": "imagePath/Desert_0.jpg?itok=6YHK_afq",
        "price": "$12.00"
    }
]
```

I'm working on a swing application in Java in which I need to fetch data from web-service

I'm following [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/) example to get data from web service and it store web service data in String.

But I want to convert this string to json and follow some example one of them is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213104/convert-string-to-jsonarray)

so I just want to know what I'm doing wrong here, or this is the right way to use this, because I don't know how to use web services in Java...

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: @Abhishek I'm trying to parse that data to json from string and I'm facing problem there...

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25418826/2587435)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000778/how-to-parse-json-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create its object first and then you need to use this

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(String);

JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("locations");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

and make sure you import this one in your code `org.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the JSONObject as follow

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(YOUR_STRING_OBJECT);
```

Check [This](http://www.json.org/java/) for more

Comment: I already use this one I have string not String object.. to use this I need to pass String object

Comment: only problem is that I'm not importing correct file I need to Import "import org.json.JSONObject;" this ... sorry and Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use google gson jar.

[Json Jar link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

and convert the object to json as below.
EmployeeRestService.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.web.object.Employee;

@Path("/getemployee")
public class EmployeeRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("/emplist")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object getEmpList() throws SQLException{

        String query = "SELECT ID,NAME,SURNAME,LOCATION_ID FROM FW_EMPLOYEE ORDER BY ID";
        Connection dbcon = (new DbConnection()).getDBConnection();
        Statement stmt = dbcon.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        while(rs.next()){
            Employee emp = new Employee();

            emp.setId(rs.getString(1));
            emp.setFirstName(rs.getString(2));
            emp.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
            emp.setLocationId(rs.getString(3));

            empList.add(emp);
        }
         dbcon.close();
         Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        return gson.toJson(empList);
    }
}
```

Json call using ajax.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val = "";
    var row ="";
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"json",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url:  "rest/getemployee/emplist",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("response:" + data);
                $.each(data, function(j, pdata) {
                    row = '<tr> <td>'+ pdata.Id +'</td><td>'+  pdata.firstName +'</td> <td>' + pdata.lastName + '</td></tr>';
                    val = val + row;
                    //$('#data').text(row);
                  // console.log(pdata.lastName);
                 });

               $("#emp").append( '<table border="1">'+ val + '</table>');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(' Error in processing! '+textStatus);

            }
        });
     });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I'm Working on a swing application

Comment: @Luffy : try to use this link , may be it will help for you .https://icewalker2g.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/using-json-in-java-swing/, Other simple way for json parsing :http://javac.in/?p=220

Comment: Thanks Imran. I'll check your suggested link look like this is what I'm looking for... Thanks :)