# How to get single object value and send to server

Tags: android, json

I have the following JSON response i want to get separate values like *CHIL SEZ IT Park,Coimbatore,Tamil Nadu,India*

**JSON String is:**

```
[
    {
        "value": "CHIL SEZ IT Park",
        "offset": 0
    },
    {
        "value": "Coimbatore",
        "offset": 18
    },
    {
        "value": "Tamil Nadu",
        "offset": 30
    },
    {
        "value": "India",
        "offset": 42
    }
]
```

Comment: Search on _google_ `how to parse JSON?`

Comment: What you have tried? so some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000778/how-to-parse-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStr);
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String value = jsonObject.getString("value");
        arrayList.add(value);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why you provide an answer directly? `wait until OP provide what he tried at least`.

Comment: Even if he hasn't tried anything, I understood the question well, and my job is to give the answer. May be he can learn or compare his code from this answer.

Comment: But this is not a way to used SO. OP know _how to search in google too_?  if OP tried nothing then why we provide direct solution. By providing direct answer we just encourage OP to post such a question in SO.

Comment: You are right, and I am sure after reading your comment OP will understand in he will keep this thing in mind in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place this function and pass the jsonString. You will get the ArrayList from the JSON.

```
public ArrayList<String> getPlaceName(String jsonString){
    ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int x=0;x<array.length();x++){
            places.add(array.getJSONObject(x).getString("value"));
        }

    }catch (JSONException e){}
    return places;
}
```